# KQL summarize by continues data

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a table that represents events in time windows (ordered by start time):

| Row | Event | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | B | 0.9 | 2 |
| 3 | C | 10 | 15 |
| 4 | A | 16 | 17 |
| 5 | C | 17 | 18 |

I want to summarize all the windows in a way so if the `StartTime` of the current row is not bigger than 1.5 + the `EndTime` of the previous row, it should be considered as the same window, and list all the events there.

The expected output:

| Row | StartTime | EndTime | Events |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | [A, B] |
| 2 | 10 | 18 | [C, A] |

Since the start time of `B` is smaller than `1+1.5` (so rows 1 and 2 are combined) but the start time of the first `C` (10) is bigger than `2+1.5` so it should be considered as a new row, and rows 3, 4, and 5 should be combined as well.

How can I do that with KQL in Azure Data Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code to achieve your requirement.

```
datatable(Row:int, Event:string, StartTime:real, EndTime:real)
[
    1, 'A', 0, 1,
    2, 'B', 0.9, 2,
    3, 'C', 10, 15,
    4, 'A', 16, 17,
    5, 'C', 17, 18,
]
| order by Row asc
| extend com1 = iif((StartTime-prev(EndTime)) <= 1.5, prev(Row),Row)
| extend com2=iif(com1==prev(Row),prev(com1),com1)
| project-away com1
| summarize Row=row_number(),StartTime = min(StartTime), EndTime = max(EndTime), Events = make_set(Event) by com2
| project-away com2
```

**My Result:**

[image]